# actionview::template::error(undefined method 'html_safe' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am a beginer in ruby and I want to write a plugin for redmine.
I have written a plugin which was running since I use 'flash[:var]' in a controller of my plugin. Now when I want to access to all my pages I have an error message that I not understand.

Ruby version : ruby 1.9.3p484

Rails version : rails 3.2.19

[this is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxw2i.png)
[image: The error message]

thank you for your answers.

EDIT:

[this is the application_helper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmsle.png)

[image: the application_helper]

Comment: What is in line 306 of application helper?  Can you post that method

Comment: Could you write text in these images down to your question? This will keep StackOverflow consistent and transparent for search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you ran into situations in which you have `nil` values in your `flash`. Imagine you have a `flash` like `{ error: nil }`, then you would call `v.html_safe` in the `content_tag` - what will cause the error.

You might want to extract all values from the `flash` that are `present?`, before calling `content_tag`:

```
def render_flash_messages
  flash.select { |k, v| v.present? }.map do |type, text|
    content_tag(:div, text.html_safe, class: "flash #{type}", id: "flash_#{typ}")
  end.join
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the `nil` to `string` using `.to_s` method

**Problem**

When you try to call `.html_safe` on `nil` value it will throw the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `html_safe' for nil:NilClass
```

*For example*

```
[8] project_rails »  html_content = nil
=> nil
[9] project_rails »  html_content.html_safe
NoMethodError: undefined method `html_safe' for nil:NilClass
from (pry):9:in `__pry__'
```

**Solution**

You can convert the `nil` to string using `.to_s`

*For example*

```
[10] project_rails »  html_content = nil
=> nil
[11] project_rails »  html_content.to_s.html_safe
=> ""
[12] project_rails »
```

So your code should be like this

```
def render_flash_messages
    s = ''
    flash.each do |k,v|
        s << content_tag('div',v.to_s.html_safe, :class => "flash #{k}", :id => "flash_#{k}")
    end
    s.html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you put `nil` into the flash which is something Redmine's `render_flash_messages` method is not designed to handle.

Changing that method to deal with nil values will work but is not something you should do from a Redmine plugin. Instead, find out where and why in your plugin you put `nil` into the flash and simply don't do it.