# Redmine Plugin trashed by errant flash statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I accidentally put a bad flash statement in my Redmine Plugin, and now my entire Redmine is trashed. No matter what I do, I get the following invincible error message:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `html_safe' for
 :value:Symbol):
     54:     <div id="sidebar">
     55:         <%= yield :sidebar %>
     56:         <%= view_layouts_base_sidebar_hook_response %>
     57:     </div>
     58: 
     59:     <div id="content">
     60:         <%= render_flash_messages %>   app/helpers/application_helper.rb:316:in `block in
 render_flash_messages'   app/helpers/application_helper.rb:315:in
 `render_flash_messages'   app/views/layouts/base.html.erb:57:in
 `_app_views_layouts_base_html_erb__1290735862753404915_23873920'
```

Fortunately, this exact problem has [happened before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578286/impossible-to-delete-a-flash)

Unfortunately, none of the solutions proposed work for me, even though they worked for the guy who asked that question.

I generated a new secret key with the following command, taken straight from the [Redmine tutorial](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/redmineinstall#Step-5-Session-store-secret-generation):

```
bundle exec rake generate_secret_token
```

I restart the WEBrick server -- to no avail. I played around with the mentioned "rescue" item, but couldn't really figure out how to make it work.

Does anyone know how to fix this devastating bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI -- manually changing the key in:

```
 config/initializers/secret_token.rb
```

slayed this deadly error